# Getting value from table that is empty in sqlite android-Showing Null Pointer Exception

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I'd like to get a value from a table. If the column does not contain any value, then I am going to insert one.

If there is a value, I want to notify the user that a value was inserted already. When my table does not contain anything it shows an error as `Java Null Pointer Exception`. I want to get a null value from my table. Please help.

```
                   String qu="select * from userinfos";
                   c=db.rawQuery(qu,null);

                   int count = c.getCount();

                   String[] values = new String[count + 1];
                   int i = 0;
                   for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {
                       values[i] = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("mail"));
                       Toast.makeText(FiveActivity.this, values[i],Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                       i++;
                    }  


                   i=0;
                   if(values[i].equals(null))
                   {
                   String    Query =    "insert into userinfos (mail,pass) values ('"+ mailuser+ "','" + password + "')";
                   db.execSQL(Query);
                   Toast.makeText(FiveActivity.this,"Values Inserted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
                       Toast.makeText(FiveActivity.this,"Already one Email-Id:"+ values[i]+" "+"you given. if you want to insert new mail and password then go to Delete app",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                   }
```

Comment: Check first your `count` value  `if(count==0){No data found} else {data available}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to check your `count` value like below:

```
 c=db.rawQuery(qu,null);

 int count = c.getCount();

 if(count==0)
{
////// No data found
} 
 else
{
 /////data available
}
```

> getCount ()

Returns the numbers of rows in the cursor

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getCount

Answer (score 0):

this is a simple fonction to manage Usertable or others:

```
/**
     * Check if data exist in table
     * 
     * @param table
     *            The table to check data
     * @param whereArgs
     *            The conditions to check the data
     * @return boolean Return True while data exist; False while data not exist
     */
    public boolean isDataExist(String table, String column, String[] whereArgs) {
        boolean result = false;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String sql = "select * from " + table + " where " + column + " = ?";
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(sql, whereArgs);
        if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            result = true;
        }
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        return result;
    }
```